# How to run vb.net exe in PHP ONLINE

Tags: php, vb.net

I have created a vb.net program and get the exe file and i'm trying to run it in web using PHP.
In localhost, it is running smoothly with these codes:

```
<?php

 $answer = exec("myexecutablefile.exe");
 echo $answer; 

?>
```

But when i upload it online (shared hosting) , the executable file is not appearing anymore. Can anyone help me how am i able to run exe file on my online website. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely, the shared hosting doesn't allow exec(). Second, the shared hosting IS a Windows-based host, right?

Comment: there is a directive in the php.ini file that you can turn off functions with, you can check it with something like this `echo ini_get('disable_functions');`  depending on your hosting you may not be able to turn it on.

Comment: Is your shared hosting server actually running Windows?

Comment: @timoschwarzer it's a linux shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Windows executables on a Linux based shared hosting service, as you probably can't install and run Wine or something like this.